# Inappropriate Profiles

Tags: discussion, users

Is it allowed to have inappropriate profile pictures and usernames?
I would like to point out a specific user right now: [Dmitry Fucintv](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/8234/dmitry-fucintv)
His (I'm assuming it's a he) profile picture is someone (maybe himself) swearing.
His username: *Dmitry Fucintv*, the *Fucintv* part, I think is suggesting the F word ing TV.  Would that be appropriate?

EDIT: The profile picture has been changed, so there is no need to talk any more about this specific user. However, the discussion can continue if anyone wants to chime in about inappropriate pictures in profiles in a more general sense.

Comment: This issue is being worked. Thank you for bringing it to our attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is solved.
He has changed his profile picture.
Thank you everyone.

Comment: I would like to add that he changed his profile picture with a very cooperative spirit.